# Correctly decoding string from bs4 tag

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup, decode

Im building trying to decode this scraped string correctly, but i dont know in what codec the string encoded when it is scraped:

this is the string:

`s_tag = BeautifulSoup('<b>mặt trong, phía trong, phần trong, bên trong</b>')`

however when it get the string in this way 
`print(s_tag.string)`
i get as output -> `lá»n trong ra ngoÃ i`
as you can see some of the characters have been transformed. The `utf-encoding is utf-8` and the language is vietnamese

Im having a hard time finding out what to do, because i dont know where to look

any help would be great

Comment: What terminal do you use? When I do `s_tag = BeautifulSoup('<b>mặt trong, phía trong, phần trong, bên trong</b>', 'html.parser');print(s_tag.text)` it prints correctly `mặt trong, phía trong, phần trong, bên trong`

Comment: I also get correct string on Linux Mint with terminal which use UTF-8. On Windows people sometimes have problem because console/terminal/cmd.exe may use `latin1` or `cp1250` and it needs to change some settings in registers to use `utf-8`: https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8

Comment: BTW: sometimes page in head has information that it uses `utf-8` but someone put text in different encoding and then you have to test different [encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). There is also module [chardet](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) to detect encoding.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I'm using fedora (linux terminal?)

Comment: @furas so i looked at the encoding of the response. The output is ```{'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': ''}```, i suspect that it is because there is no language set

Comment: @AndrejKesely thats weird, when i run the code i provided in a python terminal it does work correctly, i must be doing something wrong when either requesting, and selecting the html tag

Comment: Also, ```response.endcoding``` returns ```ISO-8859-1```

Comment: @rassenguy When you load HTML page, try to do `BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url).content.decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser' )` Note the `.content.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: @AndrejKesely this worked for me, thanks

Comment: sometimes it happend - someone define some encoding in HTML header (or in web server settings) but later it copy (from editor) text which has different encoding. As I remember in old Microsoft web servers default encoding was `ISO-8859-1` but all other web servers used `utf-8` as standard. This way someone could put text with `utf-8` (because it was standard for most servers) but  Microsoft web servers could send in header that text on page uses  `ISO-8859-1`.